# Rrror on running selenium python script - self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am using selenium with python and I try to click on element below.
But every time shows the error (in starting was working) only getting error on this line and have tried CSS selector id and all.

```
  <span class="avatar" ng-click="showBlock($event);">
                        <img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="user image">
                    </span>
```

selenium code ::

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//img[@alt="user image"]'))).click()
```

ERROR::

```
 self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 self.error_handler.check_response(response)

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="user image"> is not clickable at point (1333, 34). Other element would receive the click: <div id="page_preloader" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)
```

Comment: try adding sleep and see if its working , else use browser actions

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/41895/40022

Answer (score 1):

The error `Other element would receive the click: <div id="page_preloader">` means that the element `page_preloader` is above the element you try to click on. When Selenium tries to click on an element it checks if the click would go onto that element, it does not allow clicking on other elements.

These are situation I got this error:

- There really is an element on top of the element you want to click on, it could be transparent and not visible with your eyes. Could be that Selenium is to fast, it finds the element while for example an loading div is still there.
- The element is moving, because other elements are still being drawn. It found the element on a location, but when it tries to click another element is in its place.

I would:

- Wait until `page_preloader` is hidden before trying to interact with the page.
- Wait until the element is clickable instead of located. Located could also mean hidden, it just needs to be in the DOM. Not visible or clickable. Try: [element_to_be_clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)